# How can I import multiple xsd files to validate in xQuery Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I import multiple xsd files to validate in xQuery Marklogic.

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "/schema/a.xsd", "/schema/b.xsd";
```

And if there is possibility to validate via Marklogic

Comment: If the answers provided are sufficient, please mark one as accepted. Otherwise, please elaborate on the question so that others may be able to help

Answer (score 5):

Create one schema which imports both of your schemas into a single namespace and import that aggregate schema into MarkLogic

Answer (score -1):

if your question is how do you validate an xsd (schema) document 
rather than how do you use an xsd to validate an xml file 
xsd documents are schema validatable xml documents

validate { doc("file.xsd")}

this validates file.xsd against the butin xml schema schema

- or using any of the methods to load an xml document

i if you simply want to import multiple schema documents 
just use as many import statements as needed